# AS3 Change saturation on rollover with Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, rollover

I know this is asked a lot but I spent 4 hours searching and trying and nothing works. I am very new to Flash and AS3 so please bear with me.

At the beginning I want my image to be like 50% black and white and when I rollover it should regain the orignal saturation (not instantly, but fading to it). When the mouse is down the image should go back to 50% black and white.

I found [this](http://www.senocular.com/flash/source/?id=0.169) wonderful thing but the code is pretty complex and I don't know how to apply it to my idea.

I'm grateful for every tip!

Comment: 4 hours !! Just 4 hours !! If I've posted a question for every problem where I've spent just 4 hours, I'll have hundreds of questions posted here yet now !! Take your time, search, and search and search again, don't be hurried ... Also I don't see any code (any try) in your question ...

Comment: yes, there is no code because I don't know what to do! everything I found out so far is that it's not as simple and I need fancy ColorFilters. thank you for not helping at all.

Comment: When I look to your question, I don't see any effort, 4 hours is nothing, and sometimes I spend more more hours than 4 hours just to answer or resolve a problem here in SO ! I try to help as I can, and I'm not get paid for that ...

Comment: @BenQCat, we need code cos then it's easier to see how you're doing anything... Is your image imported to **Library** or loaded by code using `Loader`? Have you used a tween class like Caurina or Greensock before (to animate changes over time)? Do you understand what bitmap data really means?... It seems a lot of things now but that's just how real graphics programming works in most languages. Where it looks simple its because a lot is done for the user. Just say or show what you can handle at present.

Comment: I imported the image into the flash library and no I haven't used anything like that before (only a simple motion tween where no programming is necessary). I started getting into Flash yesterday. Bitmap data? Nope. I know I probably have a lot to learn but I'm willing to! I just don't know where to begin. and thank you very much for taking the time!

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way is to use [ColorMatrix](https://github.com/gskinner/AS3Libs/blob/master/ColorMatrix/com/gskinner/geom/ColorMatrix.as) class provided by Grant Skinner - it allows to adjust saturation in range [-100, 100]:

here is an example how to make display object black and white:

```
    var matrix:ColorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
    matrix.adjustSaturation(-100);
    var filter:ColorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter (matrix.toArray());

    //apply black and white filter to any DisplayObject
    myImage.filters = [filter];
```

UPD:

For tweening again the simplest way is to utilize [gtween](http://www.gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/) (there is solution based on GreenSock | TweenLite with the same functionality, but I used to `GTween` as a more lightweight solution)

You can download sources from the [link](http://www.gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/), here is the copy/paste from *GTweenColorAdjust* [demo](http://www.gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/demos/GTweenColorAdjust.swf) that changes saturation and contrast:

```
        ColorAdjustPlugin.install();
        new GTween(image, 3, {saturation:-100, contrast:70}, {repeatCount:0, reflect:true});
```

Comment: yeah but he wants a tween also... slowly fade to full colour. Maybe some `enterFrame` to check against a variable like `maxAmount` and increment as needed.. but anyways consider Asker thinks "ColorFilters" are too fancy  so they will probably faint when it comes to setting up all the code.

Comment: The GTweenColorAdjust seems to be what I want (without the contrast change) but I'm not sure how I can use it. I downloaded GTween, but do I need to install it? Put it in the flash library?

Comment: It should be in class path of your project - so available with auto-complete (exact settings depends on whether you use Flash Pro or other IDE)

Comment: alright so I manged to add in to the class path and I can open the ColorAdjust Demo... How can I view the code? There's jsut "// See associated class file for all code.". Where is the associated class file!? Maybe if I stare at it long enough it'll just click. Sorry this must be super basic but again.. it's all new for me.